# How to cast a column e.g (WRS.WidgetSubCategoryName as WidgetSubCategory) in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I'm trying to `CAST` column in my database table, I saw other example that shows how you can cast columns in SQL Server. This is the syntax

```
CAST (expression AS data_type)
```

e.g.

```
CAST(WidgetName AS VARCHAR(50))
```

How can I cast `(WRS.WidgetSubCategoryName as WidgetSubCategory)`?

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is WidgetSubCategory a user defined datatype? If not, then your question doesn't make sense. A column name is not a datatype. A property of a column is a datatype and you can cast a value to a datatype. You don't cast it to a column, that doesn't work.

Comment: yes is a user defined data type

Comment: Well in general user defined datatypes like this are a pain to deal with. You would be better off defining your column as a system datatype instead. Take a look at this article. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-alias-types